# How to merge multiple models in serializers / views Django REST Framework?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I'm a beginner, don't throw your slippers to me.
The example is degenerate, but ... There is an post model with text and owner. Each post is associated with its address, so posts have coordinates stored in a separate table.
At this stage, I can create a post with coordinates by overriding the create () method.

```
# models.py

    User = get_user_model()
    class Post(models.Model):
        owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        description = models.TextField(null=False, blank=True)
    
    
    class Address(models.Model):
        post = models.OneToOneField(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        lat = models.FloatField('Latitude', blank=True, null=True)
        lng = models.FloatField('Longitude', blank=True, null=True)

# serializer.py

    class AddressDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Address
            fields = [
                'lat',
                'lng',
            ]
    
    
    class PostDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        owner = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
        addr_point = AddressDetailSerializer(many=False)
    
        class Meta:
            model = Post
            fields = [
                'id',
                'description',
                'owner',
                'addr_point',
            ]
    
        def create(self, validated_data):
            addr_point_data = validated_data.pop('addr_point')
            post = Post.objects.create(**validated_data)
            Address.objects.create(post=post, **addr_point_data)
            return post
# views.py

    class PostCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):
        queryset = Post.objects.all()
        serializer_class = PostDetailSerializer
```

Now I do not understand at all how to display information about each post / posts in the format:

```
{
"owner": "admin"
"description": "blablabla",
"addr_point": {
"lat": 123,
"lng": 123
}
}
```

All my variations of serializers / views either don't work or can't output coordinate fields.

UPD:
For example, I use the following view to get information about some post:

```
# view.py    
class PostDetailView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
        serializer_class = PostDetailSerializer
        queryset = Post.objects.all()
```

But I get AttributeError: 'Post' object has no attribute 'addr_point'.

I will be very glad for tips on which direction to move!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow - can you set up a debugger and step through to find out where it's not working?  Or can you post more specific information about what you're trying and what is not working?  ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may help)

Comment: Hi, Matthew! I tried to add information. You can find it in the end of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to retrieve a `Post` instance using `PostDetailSerializer`, it will look for attributes listed in `PostDetailSerializer.Meta.fields`.

So in `addr_point` its accessing `post.addr_point` which doesn't exist in your model.

I would suggest a couple of changes:

```
# models.py
class Address(models.Model):
    post = models.OneToOneField(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="address")
    lat = models.FloatField('Latitude', blank=True, null=True)
    lng = models.FloatField('Longitude', blank=True, null=True)

# serializers.py
class PostDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    address = AddressDetailSerializer(many=False)

        class Meta:
            model = Post
            fields = [
                'id',
                'description',
                'owner',
                'address',
            ]
```

- In `Address.post` field, we added `related_name` parameter so we can access the reverse relationship using the string specified. In this case, we can access the address of a post through `post.address`.
- In `PostDetailSerializer` we changed `addr_point` to `address`. This is so when serializing a `post` instance, `post.address` actually exists.